# springboot server returns error 400 after post request using postman

Tags: json, spring-boot, date, post, postman

whenever I try to send this over postman:

```
{
    "date": "2021-11-05 12:32:32",
    "start": "start",
    "destination": "destination",
    "provider": "provider",
    "driver":1,
    "vehicule":1
}
```

i get an error 400, bad request, i'm using both the @restController and @requestBody annotations while also setting the content type to json.

i get this error on the debugger:

```
2021-11-09 16:57:52.086  WARN 11748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2021-11-06 12:32:32.0": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2021-11-06 12:32:32.0': Cannot parse date "2021-11-06 12:32:32.0": while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX', parsing fails (leniency? null)); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2021-11-06 12:32:32.0": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2021-11-06 12:32:32.0': Cannot parse date "2021-11-06 12:32:32.0": while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX', parsing fails (leniency? null))
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 17] (through reference chain: com.siam.HRAssistTool.Entity.Schedule["date"])]
```

I don't understand how i should fix this what i assume date format related issue

when I remove the time from the json body and only leave the date, I get this error:

```
2021-11-09 17:34:55.418  WARN 11748 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.siam.HRAssistTool.Entity.Vehicule` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.siam.HRAssistTool.Entity.Vehicule` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 8, column: 20] (through reference chain: com.siam.HRAssistTool.Entity.Schedule["vehicule"])]
```

my schedule entity:

```
@Entity
public class Schedule implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id ; 
    private Date date ; 
    private String Start; 
    private String destination;
    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Staff driver; 
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Vehicule vehicule; 
    private String provider;
    //constructors, getters and setters 
}
```

my controller :

```
@RestController
public class ScheduleController {

    @Autowired
    ScheduleService scheduleService; 

    @PostMapping(value="/schedule/create")
    public @ResponseBody String createSchedule( @RequestBody Schedule schedule) {
        System.out.println(schedule.toString());

        return scheduleService.addSchedule(schedule);
        
    }
//other crud operation
}
```

Comment: Please add the `Controller` and also your model classes, otherwise, we can't help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, replace `Date` with `LocalDate`, which is part of the new Java Time API. with this you can configure Jackson to handle serialization and deserialization of such a complex type easily. Add the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then configure Jackson accordingly:

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);

    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Then, please avoid using Entities in your `Controller`, either as a response or request type. Instead, use DTOs which are specific representations for your core model Entities.

```java
public class ScheduleCreationDto {
    private LocalDate date; 
    private String Start; 
    private String destination;
    private Long driverId;      // I am guessing the ID is a Long
    private Long vehiculeId;    // I am guessing the ID is a Long
    private String provider;
    
    //constructors, getters and setters 
}
```

This should now be used as the request body:

```java
@RestController
public class ScheduleController {

    @Autowired
    ScheduleService scheduleService; 

    @PostMapping(value="/schedule/create")
    public @ResponseBody String createSchedule(@RequestBody ScheduleCreationDto scheduleCreationDto) {
        return scheduleService.addSchedule(schedule);
    }
    
    //other crud operation
}
```

You also need to change `ScheduleService` so that it creates a `Schedule` based on `ScheduleCreationDto`. Most of the properties require a simple mapping, but others (`driverId` and `vehiculeId`) requires you to actually get those Entities from the Database using the provided ID. Something similar to the following should be done in your `ScheduleService`:

```java
@Service
public class ScheduleService {

    @Autowired
    ScheduleRepository scheduleRepository; 

    @Autowired
    DriverRepository driverRepository; 

    @Autowired
    VehiculeRepository vehiculeRepository; 

    public String addSchedule(ScheduleCreationDto scheduleCreationDto) {
        Optional<Driver> driver = driverRepository.findById(scheduleCreationDto.getDriverId());
        Optional<Vehicule> vehicule = vehiculeRepository.findById(scheduleCreationDto.getVehiculeId());

        if (driver.isPresent() && vehicule.isPresent()) {
            Schedule schedule = new Schedule(scheduleCreationDto.getDate(), scheduleCreationDto.getStart(), 
                scheduleCreationDto.getDestination(), driver.get(), vehicule.get(), scheduleCreationDto.getProvider());
            scheduleRepository.save(schedule);    
        }
    
        return // whatever String you want to return, you should actually return the created Schedule, but that is a different topic
    }

    //other crud operation
}
```

Comment: do you think it's possible to implement model mapper to improve this ?

Comment: Something like mapstruct (https://mapstruct.org/)? Definitely, but there is one thing it will not do for you. Getting `driver` and `vehicule` from the Database. I personally don't like that much these magical mappers because once you want to do something a little bit different that the standard it gets messy. I prefer to be explicit about the mappings I need in the code. But that is just my personal taste.

Comment: thank you with some tweaking this managed to work i appreciate your help

Comment: Awesome! What did you change? So that I can update my answer and help others that might have the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: findById() returns an optional so to handle this better you have to set exceptions after each one i believe that's all i changed really.

Comment: Thanks! I've reviewed the implementation ;)

Answer (score 0):

400 error bad request with postman and Spring Boot API, in my case, happend for three reasons:

1.The first, is that the json format for the request is wrong, like sending:

```
    { key: value }
```

Or:

```
    { "key" : "value"
```

This is clarely not you case.

2.The second cause was sending the keys different from what the object was expecting.For example:

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> save(@RequestResponse @Valid 
    ClassOfReciveObject reciveObject){

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("OK");
    }
```

If the ClassOfObjectRecived has properties :

```
{
    public String age;
    public String name;
}
```

And you are sending in postman others keys, you will get a bad Request

```
{
     "country":"Brazil",
     "Continent":"America"
}
```

3.The third case i got this error was because of the private access modifier for the atributes of this class, change it for public, or find ways to resolve it

```
    public class ClassOfObjectRecived {
    public String param1;
    public String param2;
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33047694)